# Select all elements within a range of attribute ID's and return specific elements

Tags: java, xpath

The code below will output a list of element ID's, and then plug those ID's into another xpath query. With the end goal to return specific child elements from each ID. This code works, however It is VERY slow, and will take far too long for anyone to want to wait, since there are a large amount of ID's. It will also return all elements, not specific ones that I choose.

1. Is there a a one-line query that will **select a range of attribute id's?**
2. Is there a better way to return elements that I want, **without using another xpath query**?

Here is what I have so far:

```
String expression = "MyComplexQueryHere/@ID-REF";    //Returns all IDs
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); // Get Nodelist
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) 
{
    Node nNode = nodeList.item(i);

    String expression2 = String.format("MyComplexElements/Element[@ID=\"%s\"]", nNode.getTextContent()) ;

    NodeList childList = (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression2).evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for (int k = 0; k < childList.getLength(); k++)
    {
        Node kNode = childList.item(k);
        System.out.println(kNode.getNodeName());
        System.out.println(kNode.getTextContent());
    }
}
```